# Extracting a key-value pair from a web service XML response

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, web-services

I'm working with C# and the .NET 2.0 framework in Visual Studio 2010.
I'm trying to extract a URL which is returned by a web service. 
This URL is returned in an array of features containing keys and values. (I think this is similar to what I learned in school is called a **hash table**).

My intellisense doesn't pick up anything useful and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is the code. What goes in `serverInfo.FeatureSet[]`?

```
public string wfl_reqURL(string username, string password)
{
    MyWorkflow.ServerInfo serverInfo = new MyWorkflow.ServerInfo();
    myURL = serverInfo.FeatureSet[];
}
```

This is how it's described in the WSDL. `FeatureSet` is being returned as an array with a string key and a string value:

```xml
<ServerInfo>
  <FeatureSet>
    <Feature>
      <Key>FileUploadUrl</Key>
      <Value>http://localhost/transferindex.php</Value>
    </Feature>
  </FeatureSet>
</ServerInfo>
```

Have I provided enough detail about my problem? Most of the information I've found seems to be about how to *create* such arrays in web services, not *select* one *from* a web service as I'd like to do.

Comment: They are usually called Dictionaries in c#. Have you tried just `FeatureSet["FileUploadUrl"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
object neededItem = null;
foreach (string item in serverInfo.FeatureSet.Keys)
{
    if (item == "FileUploadUrl")
    {
        neededItem = serverInfo.FeatureSet[item];
        break;
    }
}
if (neededItem != null)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Hmm I like the idea of searching via "FileUploadUrl" but this code won't work.. Keys there after FeatureSet doesn't work with me, and I get bugs with the object and item. But am still working it out.. will post if i figure it out and noone else does.

Comment: to break it down a bit.. this doesn't work: foreach (string item in serverInfo.FeatureSet.Keys)
because of cannot convert MyWorkflow.serverInfo.Feature to string.

Comment: `FeatureSet` is most likely an array, not a dictionary, so you can't refer to its `Keys` property - it doesn't have such a thing. Just iterate through `FeatureSet` itself and retrieve each key for each item individually.

Comment: Yes Thanks Konrad, I actually did that.. still not working atm

Comment: Changed it to this, but get errors in foreach and [item] 'code'                string transURL = "";

                foreach (string item in serverInfo.FeatureSet.ToString())
                {
                    if (item == "FileUploadUrl")
                    {
                        transURL = serverInfo.FeatureSet[item];
                        MessageBox.Show(transURL);
                    }
                }'

Comment: @user1611224 try getting rid of the `ToString()`, you are iterating an array, and by calling that, you are asking it to spit out the string representation of that array, which isn't something you can iterate.

Comment: "Just iterate through `FeatureSet` itself" - not through `FeatureSet.ToString` or anything like that

Comment: Well tbh That's the first thing I tried, and that's why i put the .ToString because of the error. That took care of the error, but produced something ridiculous (each letter of the array name instead of what's IN it).. I am starting to think there is somethign majorly wrong with the call itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using c# 3.5 then something in linq like

```
myURL = serverInfo.FeatureSet.First(o=>o.Key == "FileUploadUrl").Value
```

Comment: Thanks.. unfortunately it must be compatible with .NET 2.0. I don't get the "First" or "Key" (i do get "Keys") as options

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the data type. Changing the code to this solved the problem, albeit in a messy way. I thought it had something to do with types and how it was defined...either as dictionary or arrays, but it was a bit different than I'd thought...

```
foreach( MyWorkFlow.Feature feature in serverInfo.FeatureSet) {
    if (feature.Key.ToString() == "FileUploadUrl") {
        string myURL = feature.Value;
        Console.WriteLine(myURL);
    }
```